# Retrieve data from Authentication table from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on mobile application and I have two types of users admin and a regular user, I'm working on block user story and I saw in Firebase web-app that I can disable an account manually, I tried many ways to block users like save the user's email in real-time database and a flag that presenting the status of the account if it's blocked or disabled or normally working sometimes it worked and other time not, it didn't work well is there any way I can retrieve the data about specific (by user's email address) user and block them from Authentication?

here is the code that I was working with

```
FirebaseRefernce ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Name1=Name.getText().toString().trim();
                    String name1="";
                    String name2;
                    int flag=0;
                    for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        name2=d.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        if(name2.equals(Name1) )
                        {
                            flag=1;
                            name1=d.getKey().toString();
                            ref1.child(name1).child("flag").setValue("1");
                            Toast.makeText(blockuser.this, "User Blocked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),adminpage.class));
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

and in the login page where the system must check if the account's status

```
    FirebaseRefernce ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                    String childEmail = "";
                    for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        childEmail = data.child("email").getValue().toString();
                        if(childEmail.equals(email))
                        {
                            if(data.child("flag").getValue().toString().equals("1"))
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "User Blocked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. When you run this code, which line doens't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: onDataChange in both classes sometimes it's going in sometimes not

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whats wrong in there, could you provide more details? onDatachange is not being called?.

But your user structure could be better, instead of retrieving your whole users database at the login page and then looping through all of them, you should only retrieve the one you want and check for the flag. If you want to do this by email then set the key of your realtime database to be the email when you create a new user.

You could also check at [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) that the data you're trying to set is correct.

Comment: Sometimes it works i get the data that i want and sometimes i never get my hand on data i uses debbuger and code jumps from ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {...} to the end });

Comment: it seems a bit weir, maybe there is a connection error, you could try putting a breakpoint inside onCancelled method and print the error. One of those two is supposed to be called always.